# Microsoft GraphAPI 403 on authentication methods ( Node - @azure/msal-node package )

Tags: node.js, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the authentication methods for a user, in my scopes, I have tried 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' which gives me the 403 error,

I have Delegated permissions of: User.Read, User.Read.All, UserAuthenticationMethod.Read, UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All
and application permissions of UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All

All of which have a status of 'Granted for '

but I have also tried adding 'https://graph.microsoft.com/UserAuthenticationMethod.Read' and 'https://graph.microsoft.com/UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All', when I add them, it gives me an error of invalid scopes

Here is a code snippet of where I get my token

```js
const msalConfig = {
      auth: {
        clientId: clientId,
        privateKey: this.configService
          .get('AZURE_APP_PEM')
          .split('|')
          .join('\n'),
        x5c: this.configService.get('AZURE_APP_CERT').split('|').join('\n'),
        thumbprint: this.configService.get('AZURE_APP_THUMBPRINT'),
        authority: aadEndpoint + '/' + tenantId,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
      },
    };
    
    const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);
    const foundToken = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
        scopes: [ 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' ],
        
      });
```

Here That function returns the found token, Here is the code I use to call the query

```js
async callApi(api: string, tenantId: string) {
    const graphEndpoint = this.configService.get('AZURE_GRAPH_ENDPOINT');
    const token = await this.getToken(tenantId);
    const options = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token?.accessToken}`,
      },
    };
    let data = [];
    try {
      let response = await axios.get(`${graphEndpoint}/${api}`, options);
      data.push( ...response.data.value);
      while( typeof response.data['@odata.nextLink'] === "string" && response.data['@odata.nextLink'].length > 0 ) {
        response = await axios.get(response.data['@odata.nextLink'], options);
        data.push( ...response.data.value);
      }
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    }
  }
```

And in the line I am using to call this

```js
await this.callApi(`v1.0/users/${user.userPrincipalName}/authentication/methods`, user.tenantId);
```

Comment: Could you also include the graph query you are passing to fetch the authentication methods?

Comment: I added all the other relevent code of how I am using this,  but the only thing I pass into Fetch is the token, Getting the token is handled by @azure/msal-node, Does that help?

Comment: Can you decode the access token and check whether the roles are present?

Comment: I went to get the token, and now it is working, I am guessing one of the permissions took a while to take effect or somthing? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it just took a while for the permission to take effect, I just tried it and it started working